# Мониторинг трафика в Android

Tags: android, сеть

Сап хэшкод, нужно как-то посмотреть какие post/get запросы отправляет определенное приложения под андроид. Это можно глянуть в android studio? Или в genymotion? Вообще интересуют любые варианты, главное что бы смог все это увидеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.net-security.org/article.php?id=1901

Вариант - использовать [сниффер](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) трафика на устройстве.

Answer (score 0):

Обычный снифер, выключите перед этим все остальное, что может слать запрсоы в сеть и смотрите.